# Need help in rendering a grid view using jquery mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-mobile

Hey guys I am implementing this app, where I am retrieving images from a db using php, and echoing back a div tag, which has all the info about how the images are to be displayed on the screen (basically a grid view). I am using jquery mobile for generating the grid view. I know for sure my backend is returning the correct divs in the correct format. So my best guess is that the data gets echoed from the backend before jquery is ready to render it into  a grid view, so do you have any suggestions or solutions for this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: insert some code or put a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess because you didn't provide any code, but If you think that you are calling jquery when it's not yet loaded, then try wrapping your jquery code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
         // use jquery here: e.g. $('#content').show();
    }, false);
</script>
```

or like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         // use jquery here: e.g. $('#content').show();
    });
</script>
```

This way your code is executed when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry about the delay, here is a small piece of code which I wrote today and it seems to work pretty well. The sample.php returns the grid view in html format.

```
jQuery(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    jQuery.get('sample.php', function(data) {
            jQuery('#sample').append(data);
      });
```